# How to get timezone name from ISO date string?

Tags: momentjs

I am using [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) and I have date string in ISO format `2013-01-01T00:00:00+08`.

I need to get the timezone name from such string. For example, for `2013-01-01T00:00:00+08` I need `America/Los_Angeles` - I dont't care which timezone it will be if there are more timezones in `+08` span.

How can I do it with moment-timezone? I tried `moment('2013-01-01T00:00:00+08').tz()` but it returns `undefined`.

Comment: `America/Los_Angeles` and `+08` are not, in general, the same timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Plz check this link, [moment zone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/)

where u can find all the things related to moment Zone.

Zone object has

```
{
name    : 'America/Los_Angeles',          // the unique identifier
abbrs   : ['PDT', 'PST'],                 // the abbreviations
untils  : [1414918800000, 1425808800000], // the timestamps in milliseconds
offsets : [420, 480]                      // the offsets in minutes
}
```

zone.name; // America/Los_Angeles
 The uniquely identifying name of the timezone.